# Get result of REST sampler in JMeter

Tags: rest, jmeter

Please show me how can get the result of REST sampler in Jmeter. Because I need to to it for checking my sampler is right or wrong

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [View results tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) and uncheck Errors and Success check boxes in order to show all responses you receive. The Response data tab will show response data :) which you can format using drop down list in the lower left part of the View Results Tree component, bellow the request tree.

When you run test with large number of requests I suggest you check Errors (to record only requests that failed) to avoid filling up the RAM.

Or even better (for advanced test verification), you can use [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions) to mark the requests/responses that failed (which doesn't have to mean only "response code != 200", you may want to include your business logic and check arbitrary response header/param).

Comment: I use JMeter 2.5 and View results tree can not get the result. So, do you have any situation like that ? I have read a article from smartrics. They said that JMeterRestSampler would not support for JMeter 2.5.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used that plugin, but it seems that it's not complicated to debug and find out which new jMeter's feature/change is breaking it. REST = ordinary HTTP Request (the plugin extends jMeter's HTTPSampler2).

Comment: ah, JMeterRestSampler (by smartrics) is used in my project, so i have to research on it. but any way, thanks mbonaci for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Add a 'View Results Tree View' to your testplan to see how the tests run.
When clicking on a test you can view the request/response data.

Next you might want to validate that response; add a 'Response Assertion' to your test
where you can match the response to anything you want.